# Pyinstaller and py2exe result in error: "tuple index out of range"

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, py2exe, openpyxl, easygui

This is my first time using Pyinstaller so please bear with me. Why does the following result in an error? How do I fix it. I am trying to convert the python program I wrote into a windows .exe.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pyinstaller C:\Users\evank\Desktop\Package\program.py
121 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.2.1
121 INFO: Python: 3.6.1
121 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.15063-SP0
127 INFO: wrote C:\WINDOWS\system32\program.spec
127 INFO: UPX is not available.
129 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\evank\\Desktop\\Package', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32']
129 INFO: checking Analysis
131 INFO: Building Analysis because out00-Analysis.toc is non existent
131 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
138 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
140 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('PyInstaller==3.2.1', 'console_scripts', 'pyinstaller')()
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 90, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 46, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 788, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 734, in build
    exec(text, spec_namespace)
  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 212, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 161, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 317, in assemble
    excludes=self.excludes, user_hook_dirs=self.hookspath)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 560, in initialize_modgraph
    graph.import_hook(m)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1509, in import_hook
    source_package, target_module_partname, level)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1661, in _find_head_package
    target_module_headname, target_package_name, source_package)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 209, in _safe_import_module
    module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2077, in _safe_import_module
    module_name, file_handle, pathname, metadata)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2167, in _load_module
    self._scan_code(m, co, co_ast)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2585, in _scan_code
    module, module_code_object, is_scanning_imports=False)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2831, in _scan_bytecode
    global_attr_name = get_operation_arg_name()
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2731, in get_operation_arg_name
    return module_code_object.co_names[co_names_index]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

EDIT: Using py2exe also results in the same error.

Please HELP!
Thanks,
Evank28

Answer (score 4):

Ok I figured it out. Pyinstaller is not yet ready for Python 3.6 and this is the error that occurs when using Pyinstaller with Python 3.6. I unistalled Pyinstaller and installed the development verion of Pyinstaller with the following commands in Command Prompt.

```
pip uninstall pyinstaller
pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/tarball/develop
```

Then, use pyinstaller the same way as usual and it works like a charm.  The official install doesn't work for Python v3.6 yet.

```
pyinstaller myprogram.py
```