# IndexError: tuple index out of range PyInstaller

Tags: python, tuples, pyinstaller

When I use pyinstaller to convert my .py file to .exe, I got this error:-

```
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Python : 3.10

PyInstaller : 5.0 (development)

```
C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Jarvis\DCJarvis>pyinstaller JarvisFEMALE.py
490 INFO: PyInstaller: 5.0.dev0
490 INFO: Python: 3.10.0
517 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19043-SP0
520 INFO: wrote C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Jarvis\DCJarvis\JarvisFEMALE.spec
527 INFO: UPX is not available.
533 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\DELL\\Desktop\\Jarvis\\DCJarvis']
2022 INFO: checking Analysis
2022 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
2023 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
2037 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
2152 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
23739 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from 'C:\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-distutils.py'.
23741 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'C:\\Python310\\lib'
29591 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
30643 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
30654 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by C:\Python310\python.exe
31022 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Jarvis\DCJarvis\JarvisFEMALE.py
32116 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook urllib3.packages.six.moves from 'C:\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-urllib3.packages.six.moves.py'.
42783 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook site from 'C:\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-site.py'.
42803 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir 'C:\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\fake-modules'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python310\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 124, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 58, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 827, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 759, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Jarvis\DCJarvis\JarvisFEMALE.spec", line 7, in <module>
    a = Analysis(
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 311, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 155, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 473, in assemble
    priority_scripts.append(self.graph.add_script(script))
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 265, in add_script
    self._top_script_node = super().add_script(pathname)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1433, in add_script
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2850, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2301, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1505, in import_hook
    target_package, target_module_partname = self._find_head_package(
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1684, in _find_head_package
    target_package = self._safe_import_module(
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 387, in _safe_import_module
    return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2062, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2850, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2301, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1505, in import_hook
    target_package, target_module_partname = self._find_head_package(
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1684, in _find_head_package
    target_package = self._safe_import_module(
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 387, in _safe_import_module
    return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2062, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2850, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2301, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1505, in import_hook
    target_package, target_module_partname = self._find_head_package(
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1684, in _find_head_package
    target_package = self._safe_import_module(
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 387, in _safe_import_module
    return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2062, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2850, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2301, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1518, in import_hook
    submodule = self._safe_import_module(head, mname, submodule)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 387, in _safe_import_module
    return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2062, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2850, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2301, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1518, in import_hook
    submodule = self._safe_import_module(head, mname, submodule)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 387, in _safe_import_module
    return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2062, in _safe_import_module
    self._process_imports(n)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2850, in _process_imports
    target_module = self._safe_import_hook(*import_info, **kwargs)[0]
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2301, in _safe_import_hook
    target_modules = self.import_hook(
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1518, in import_hook
    submodule = self._safe_import_module(head, mname, submodule)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 387, in _safe_import_module
    return super()._safe_import_module(module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2061, in _safe_import_module
    n = self._scan_code(module, co, co_ast)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2645, in _scan_code
    self._scan_bytecode(
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2749, in _scan_bytecode
    for inst in util.iterate_instructions(module_code_object):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\util.py", line 147, in iterate_instructions
    yield from iterate_instructions(constant)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\util.py", line 139, in iterate_instructions
    yield from get_instructions(code_object)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\dis.py", line 338, in _get_instructions_bytes
    argval, argrepr = _get_const_info(arg, constants)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\dis.py", line 292, in _get_const_info
    argval = const_list[const_index]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

How do I fix this ?

Plz help me, I tried to convert more than 4 project but I got this error in all!

Comment: Please share the code where exactly you are getting the error.

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: A have a very huge program with more than 15000 lines, when I run it, it works without any error but when I am converting it to .exe, I get this error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pyinstaller and py2exe result in error: "tuple index out of range"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45112041/pyinstaller-and-py2exe-result-in-error-tuple-index-out-of-range)

Comment: I have already tried that, it doesn't work in my case!

Comment: Probably time to open an issue for pyinstaller

Comment: Or don’t use the dev build of PyInstaller.

Comment: I have used both the versions of pyinstaller (development and normal). It doesn't work in python 3.9 and 3.10, but now I have fixed the problem by degrading my python version to 3.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating your Python version should fix the issue.
I experienced the same problem until I updated to Python 3.10.2